# Enable caching of just the scripts in ajax calls that return partial views

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, browser, script-tag

I've been working on bundling up my javascript files using MVC4's razor bundling which generates a virtual path to a bundle of all my files and appends a hash code that changes when I've made changes to the files.

That all works well except when I'm adding partial views that I've fetched via jquery ajax calls. It looks like the ajax sends a request, fetches the partial, then parses it for any resource tags, like the script tag, and makes an additional ajax call but this one is synchronous. It makes sense, but I don't seem to have any control over it and it defaults to caching: false.

This shows up in my network tab under XHRs like this:

nameOfJavascriptFile.js?_=14440357372

Where the _=#### is appended to prevent caching. Is there any way for me to prevent this from happening on these synchronous ajax calls that are fetching resources after making an ajax call that returns html? I really want to just rely on the bundle's hash and not this datetime stuff since it really isn't necessary for my situation.